# Difference between "none" and "swap" as a mountpoint for swap in fstab?

Tags: fstab, swap

I've seen that sometimes the entry for the swapfile in fstab is specified as "none" for the mount point and sometimes as "swap" instead. For example:

```
/swapfile none swap defaults 0 0

/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

The `fsrtab` man page says that "none" should be used, but Red Hat's documentation uses "swap" instead.

What is the difference between those two?

Comment: Are you using Red Hat?

Comment: I am using Centos.

Comment: Did you  mean `fstab`? Generally, the second field of the `fstab` is the `name`, which is usually a pathname to mount on. A swap partition does not have a pathname, so it has no meaning here. You could name it "gobbledegook" and the mounter will not care. The use of 'none' or 'swap' are just conventions, and may aid some tools in managing such partitions.

Answer (score 5):

It's only a name. You can use any string, for example: `pinkunicorn`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following may be useful: ["All about Linux swap space"](https://www.linux.com/news/all-about-linux-swap-space/)

Since swap space is a special type of filesystem, many of these parameters aren’t applicable. For swap space, add:

```
/dev/hdb1       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

where `/dev/hdb1` is the swap partition. It doesn’t have a specific mount point, hence `none`. It is of type `swap` with options of `sw`, and the last two parameters aren't used so they are entered as `0`.

The `/etc/fstab` entry for a swap file would look like this:

```
/swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0
```